# Cannot install python-libs package on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python, yum

I have been using certbot to renew my ssl certificates. I've run in to an issue recently where execution of this script fails, even with the latest version. I am given the following error:

```
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.6-66.el6_8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.1(EXPAT_2_0_1_RH)(64bit) for package: python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (CentOS-base)
       Requires: libexpat.so.1(EXPAT_2_0_1_RH)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

In doing some research, I tried to manually install the expats library:

```
yum install expats
```

I also tried

```
yum install expats21
```

Neither created a file at /usr/lib64 that matches libexpat.so.1. I tried creating symlinks but that didn't work either.

For reference, here is my repolist because according to a reddit article I found, that might be the cause but the posting did not list how to fix it:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, replace, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration
4847 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
repo id                                                              repo name                                                                                        status
CentOS-base                                                          CentOS-6 - Base                                                                                    3,627+3,086
CentOS-extras                                                        CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                         31+2
CentOS-updates                                                       CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                                      96+123
!amzn-main/latest                                                    amzn-main-Base                                                                                           5,934
!amzn-updates/latest                                                 amzn-updates-Base                                                                                        1,166
epel/x86_64                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                    11,462+1,054
google-chrome/x86_64                                                 google-chrome                                                                                                3
nodesource/x86_64                                                    Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                           144
rpmforge                                                             RHEL latest - RPMforge.net - dag                                                                     4,136+582
webtatic/x86_64                                                      Webtatic Repository EL6 - x86_64                                                                           854
yarn                                                                 Yarn Repository                                                                                                 37
repolist: 27,490
```

My question is what do I need to do to get this package installed?

Comment: What version of which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to install CentOS packages on an Amazon AMI host. You probably don't want to do that. If you want to run CentOS packages, you should probably build a CentOS host.

Also note that the `Amazon Linux 2` AMI does, in fact, support the `python-libs` package. I'm not so sure about the base `Amazon Linux` AMI.

Comment: CentOS packages definitely should not be anywhere near Amazon Linux. They aren't compatible, will conflict, and eventually will likely result in a broken instance. This also applies to EPEL, which isn't compatible with either Amazon Linux or Amazon Linux 2. If you want CentOS, just use CentOS.